# How do I remove the stationary panel of a swinging patio door for painting?

Tags: doors, painting, door-frame

I'm working on painting some exterior doors.  I'd like to remove them to properly prep and paint.  The door on the left is not a problem, I'll simply take it off the hinges.  However, the door on the right is fixed.  Is there something obvious that I should be looking for that would allow me to remove that door?   Any insight on how to approach this would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my experience those "fixed in place" doors, or faux doors if you will, are part and parcel with the frame. I have left them in place and painted very carefully to ensure either there is no overspray (I use a gun...I cheat). Or if I am painting the door myself I ensure that the corner and joints get the proper attention and prep needed to look good as a finished product as well.

Comment: @JCrosby, sounds like an answer.

Comment: @JPhi1618 the OP asked about removal and I didn't speak to that - so I left it as a comment for their convenience.

Comment: There may be vinyl strips inside hiding screws or mounting clips. The panel is probably caulked in place, though. By removing it you risk compromising its weather seal. Post detail photos of the inside if you'd like more help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've added a picture of the inside as well.